# How to make --no-edit work in git?

Tags: git

Sometimes I have to commit the same change across 2 dozen git repositories. I use a script, with the following command so I don't have to type :q two dozen times for the commit message I don't want to change:

```
git commit -a --amend --no-edit
```

Problem is, it never works. **It still opens the editor and shows me the commit message that I don't want to change.**

Can you see anything wrong with the command I've typed, or have any ideas why this wouldn't work? I am using git version 1.7.1, on centos version 2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64.

Comment: `git commit -a --amend -C HEAD`: take the existing comment from HEAD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git commit -a --amend -C HEAD`: take the existing comment from HEAD.

Comment: I do not see your problem in git 2.6.3. I do not know what git versions this bug applies to.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add content before you commit.

If you don't add anything nothing will be commited,
You can use the `-a` flag passed to the commit to also add your content.

If you want you can also type <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> to exit vim instead of the <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>.

### **P.S.**

Its about time to upgrade your git. 
Very old version with security issues.

Comment: CentOS is one of those "never upgrade anything" Linux distributions.  I'm not sure if they even patch all the CVEs (I just know I am glad I am not the one dealing with CentOS anymore :-) ).

Comment: See edited question. In every case I have already added content to the index.

Answer (score 1):

This makes no sense. `git commit --amend` is for modifying an existing commit. You are talking about making a new commit.

Do you really mean across many *repositories*, or do you perhaps mean across many *branches*?

- Within the same repository, you could use `git cherry-pick <commit>` to re-apply the same change to multiple branches. That will not require a commit message, it will pick up the message from the original one.
- In a different repository, you need to make a change to the files. Probably use `git apply < <patch_file> &&  git commit -a -m <commit message>`. Your script can supply the patch and commit message.

Comment: You can also use `git format-patch` and `git am` to copy commits across repositories, or even add repositories as a remote, fetch, and then cherry-pick.  The `am` trick is usually better with very large repositories, since otherwise they bloat up when you start combining them (even if you never merge the various DAGs you get a lot of objects).

Comment: See edited question. I am amending a commit in several different repositories. Its a part of my deployment strategy. Just trust me...